# Approximation using pythagorean theorem

Tags: geometry, circles, approximation

Im looking at the following diagram,
[image]

Here, I am interested in a relation between $a,s,c$, assuming that $r >> 1$ my first thought is to relate then using the pythagorean theorem,
$$ c^2 = a^2 + s^2$$
Is making sure an approximation a good approach and is there an alternate way to relate my variables?  Thank you in advance!

Comment: The size of $r$ has no effect on the relative accuracy of your approximation. The important variable is $\theta$. The approximation will be good only if $\theta$ is very near $0$.

Comment: For clarification, what's $c$? Is it just the distance from the upper-left corner to the top of the circle? (And if so, why is the rest of the line segment drawn?)

Comment: using law of cosines you can get angle between a and c. Using that angle you can get a better approximation of s.

Comment: @EthanBolker so as long as that condition is met I can apply pythagoras' theorem? Im unsure if this is even a right triangle...

Comment: @AaronMontgomery It is the distance between the upper-left corner and the top of the circle, that was a mistake on my part.  Will update

Comment: @Vasya How would that look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the cosine rule:
$$
c^2=(a+r)^2+r^2-2r(a+r)\cos\theta,
$$
that is:
$$
c^2=a^2+2r(a+r)(1-\cos\theta).
$$
As $\theta=s/r$, if $r\gg s$ we can approximate $\cos\theta\approx1-{1\over2}\theta^2=1-{1\over2}s^2/r^2$, which gives:
$$
c^2=a^2+s^2\left(1+{a\over r}\right).
$$
If $r\gg a$ the term $a/r$ is negligible and you obtain $c^2=a^2+s^2$.